# Replace all occurrences and regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying replace two consecutive line breaks with the HTML tag `<p/>`. So in a string such as:

```
\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

There are two consecutive occurrences of `\r\n\r\n`,

The result should be:

```
<p/><p/>
```

but with C# `String.Replace`, it only detects the first occurrence and I just get back:

```
<p/>\r\n
```

So I'm wondering if any regular expression gurus know how to detect that using regular expression?

**Edit:**

I figured the question is a bit confusing. Let me rephrase it. The requirement should be to replace any `"\r\n"` with a tag `<p/>` only if there is another "\r\n" immediately before it.

Such with the string:

```
\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

- The first `\r\n`, does not have another `\r\n` before it, nothing should be done,
- The second `\r\n`, it does have another `\r\n` before it, qualifies for replacement,
- The third `\r\n`, it does have another `\r\n` before it, also qualifies for replace.

So the result should be:

```
<p/><p/>
```

Comment: You said: "There are two consecutive occurrence of "\r\n\r\n"". I might be misunderstanding you, but `\r\n` occurs only three times in that string, so there are only 1.5 consecutive occurrences.

Comment: Show us your c# code. Docs for String.Replace (See <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx>) specify "in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string". Are you using Regex.Replace?

Comment: Sorry guys if it's confusing.  I should rephrase the question. What I want to do is, if I detect a "\r\n" right before a "\r\n", it should be replace with the tag "p". In the case above, there are two occurrences where there is a "\r\n" right before another "\r\n", such I need two "p" as the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a regular expression:

```
string tidyString = Regex.Replace(originalString, @"(?<=\r\n)\r\n", "<p/>");
```

If performance is an issue then you *might* find that rebuilding the string manually is quicker than a regex, but the drawback will be the more complicated code. (I'd probably go for the regex in 99% of situations.)

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(originalString.Length);
int startIndex = 0, nextIndex;
while ((nextIndex = originalString.IndexOf("\r\n", startIndex)) >= 0)
{
    if ((nextIndex == startIndex) && (startIndex > 0))
        sb.Append("<p/>");
    else
        sb.Append(originalString, startIndex, nextIndex - startIndex + 2);

    startIndex = nextIndex + 2;
}
sb.Append(originalString, startIndex, originalString.Length - startIndex);

string tidyString = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: oh god, I love you LukeH. You are THE MAN! Can't believe how concise your code is even with your "complicated" version. That's a piece of art. 

Just read on positive look behind and suddenly it all makes sense now. Thank you a million times.

Answer (score 1):

You have said this in a comment:

> What I want to do is, if I detect a
>   "\r\n" right before a "\r\n", it
>   should be replace with the tag "p".

This can be rephrased:

> What I want to do is, if I detect **N**
>   consecutive occurrences of "\r\n"
>   where **N > 1**, I want to replace these
>   with **N - 1** occurrences of the tag "p".

Don't believe me?

Let's say we have some fence posts:

```
|  |  |  |  |
```

If I say, "I want to detect wherever the is a fence post right before another fence post," what am I really saying? I'm saying I want to make N - 1 detections wherever there are N consecutive fence posts (again: when N > 1).

Look above; there are **five** fence posts, but **four** occurrences such as what you've described. The same holds true for detecting consecutive occurrences of "\r\n" *after the first occurrence*.

---

It sounds like rather than replace the string `"\r\n\r\n"` with `"<p/>"`, you want to replace all occurrences of `"\r\n"` *after the first occurrence* with `"<p/>"`, stripping the first occurrence out. (Your example does *not* contain two consecutive occurrences of `"\r\n\r\n"`; it contains three consecutive occurrences of only `"\r\n"`.)

If this is exactly what you want, I'd recommend simply doing what I just described: detecting a `"\r\n"` and replacing *subsequent* `"\r\n"` occurrences in the string with `"<p/>"` (until reaching a block of text that is different).

Let me know if you need any help doing that. It's also possible I've misunderstood you, of course; but this is what it looks like to me you are trying to accomplish.

<strike>*Hint: A very easy but inefficient way of doing this would involve calling `string.Split` with the string `"\r\n"` as the delimiter and using the resulting array to reconstruct the string.*</strike>

*Actually, I don't think the above hint will quite get you there, even as an inefficient solution. There are obviously other ways, though.*

Comment: Hey Dan, Actually, that's not the case.  If there is only one "\r\n", i do not want to replace with a p tag. Only if there are two "\r\n", i.e "\r\n\r\n", then I will replace it with a p. Now the special case is if there is 3rd "\r\n" after that, because there is a "\r\n" (the 2nd one) right before it, in this case, it needs to be replaced with a p as well. In the example above, such the result should be two "p" tags.

Comment: @Liming: I think I *do* understand what you are after; I may have communicated myself poorly, though. Give me just a moment to update my answer...

Comment: Ah, yes. I got you now. Yes, I can definitely String Split base on the single carriage return and then loop that way. Hm, though it will be somewhat slow due to the amount of text I have to parse... Basically, I have a whole chunk of discussion text and I need to properly wrap them in paragraphs. Empty lines with be a paragraph on their own, etc. If no regular expression way can be found, then I will probably go with this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I had to use a 2nd replace method to cater for the 3rd \r\n occurrence.

```
var input = "Line1\r\nLine2\r\n\r\n\r\n<line5>";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "(\\r\\n){2}", "<p/>");
result = Regex.Replace(result, "<p/>\\r\\n", "</p></p>");

//result equals: "Line1\r\nLine2</p></p><line5>"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only detect the first two "\r\n". The third "\r\n" is ignored.

Comment: @Liming: I added a 3rd option which perhaps suits your requirements better.

Comment: Hey Luke, sorry that I had my question phrased in a confusing way. Basically, I have a chunk of text like this "Line1<linebreak>Line2<linebreak><linebreak><linebreak><line5>" the result should be Line1<linebreak>Line2<p-tag><p-tag><line5>

Comment: @Liming: Does this solution not cater for that scenario? If it does not, then you need to explain further.

Comment: Hey @Luke Baulch, thanks a lot for your help. The problem with the approach is that it only solves the particular case I added, not the requirement.  If for instance, I add one more linebreak between line 2 and line5, this code won't work anymore again. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

`"\r\n\r\n\r\n"` isn't really "two consecutive occurrences of `"\r\n\r\n"`".  Yes, chars 1-4 and chars 3-6 are both the string `"\r\n\r\n"`, but they intersect one another.  `String.Replace` cannot take this into account.  It simply scans the string until it finds something to replace, does the replacement, and then continues scanning the string from that point on.  It doesn't scan the whole string and identify the various substrings that are to be replaced and then replaces each of them with the specified string.

Comment: Thank Dan. Yeah, I figured String.Replace wouldn't work in that case... so I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do that with regular expression